# Does Qt Builder have a built-in tool for editing a toolbar?

Tags: qt, button, icons, toolbar

Does Qt have a set of standard icons? (Like for `Back`,`Forward`, etc.)

How would I add these to a button or toolbar in Qt Creator/Designer?

Comment: I too would like an answer to this from the Qt Designer perspective. I know how to use the standard icons via their enumeration or string aliases from inside the code, but not how to do it in Qt Designer without manually editing the .ui or .qrc files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you can't add the icons directly in Designer, but you can programmatically reference them using:

`QIcon QStyle::standardIcon ( StandardPixmap standardIcon, const QStyleOption * option = 0, const QWidget * widget = 0 ) const`

The returned QIcon should be style-appropriate based on your current style. You can see the list of standardIcons [in the official documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum).